# rename all key's objects JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, database

I want to rename some of my key's object but with a map it sounds quite difficult (I'm a newbie) here is my array :

```
 "platforms": [
        {
          "id": 6,
          "name": "PC (Microsoft Windows)"
        },
        {
          "id": 11,
          "name": "Xbox"
        },
        {
          "id": 14,
          "name": "Mac"
        },
        {
          "id": 48,
          "name": "PlayStation 4"
        },
        {
          "id": 130,
          "name": "Nintendo Switch"
        }
      ],
```

And this is what i want it to be :

```
"platforms": [
        {
          "id": 6,
          "name": "PC"
        },
        {
          "id": 11,
          "name": "Xbox"
        },
        {
          "id": 14,
          "name": "Mac"
        },
        {
          "id": 48,
          "name": "PS4"
        },
        {
          "id": 130,
          "name": "Switch"
        }
      ],
```

And here is my code :

```
 const renderedResults = results.map((result, index) => {
const platformSliced = result.platforms.slice(0,3);   
return  (
                        {platformSliced.map((platform) => 
                                <span className="main-game-card-platform">
                                    {platform.name}.replace('PC (Windows Microsoft)', 'PC')
                                </span>
                        )}
        );
    });
```

It doesn't work maybe I should do a condition, but how can I write it ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an object where the keys are the strings you want changed, and the values the strings that should replace the old string.

With `.map()` method, return a new object for each item, where the `id` is unchanged. The `name` property should look first in the new "rewrites" object if the value of `name` exists as a key in the object. If it does, then the value should be used, otherwise there is no rewrite and the old `name` should be used.

```js
const rewrites = {
  "PC (Microsoft Windows)": 'PC',
  "PlayStation 4": 'PS4',
  "Nintendo Switch": 'Switch'
};

const platforms = [
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "PC (Microsoft Windows)"
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "name": "Xbox"
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "name": "Mac"
  },
  {
    "id": 48,
    "name": "PlayStation 4"
  },
  {
    "id": 130,
    "name": "Nintendo Switch"
  }
];

const rewrittenPlatforms = platforms.map(({ id, name }) => ({
  id,
  name: rewrites[name] ?? name // Use rewritten name, if present, otherwise use old name.
}));

console.log(rewrittenPlatforms);
```